# Dont run if statement if variable already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code where the resize function checks at runtime for screen width and loads a high or standard resolution version of an image.

When repeatedly resizing the width between the two CSS-defined breakpoint widths, the script appends `-large.jpg` to the filename, resulting in `imagename-large-large.jpg`.

```
   function resize(){
      $('.image').each(function() {
        var image = $(this).find('.image img');
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var highRes = src.replace(".jpg", "-large.jpg");
      });
       if ($(window).width() > 1920) {
           image.attr("src", highRes);
       }
       else {
           image.attr("src", src);
       }
    }
```

I don't know how to stop the script from appending `-large.jpg` to the filename. What is the best method to do so?

Comment: Your code won't work at all; the "src" and "highRes" variables are local variables to that `.each()` callback.

Comment: There's a lot wrong. Why do you have nested image classes?

Comment: Seriously? You used the word "if" in your question, but you couldn't figure out that you needed to add an if statement?  The rest of your code shows a complete lack of understanding of basic principles, like scope. Are you sure you are capable enough to be doing any programming at all?

Comment: @vol7ron nested image classes can be helpful for specific positioning paradigms, for masking, for specific rollover effects, or any number of other things.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson do you reallllly think that's what's going on here? I would say those are intermediate to advanced effects. Based on what we're seeing here, I would think that might be too advanced. Also, I generally wouldn't name a nested class the same thing unless necessary, just to prevent confusion in CSS and make queryselecting easier.

Comment: @vol7ron you are on point and those are advanced techniques, I agree. I guess the people who would be employing them would know when to deviate form the general best practices of not nesting elements like this and wouldn't hesitate to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you could `search` `src` for the string `-large`. Search returns `-1` if it's not found, and the position of the match if it is.

```
  $('.image').each(function() {
    var image = $(this).find('.image img');
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    if(src.search('-large') !== -1){
      // already has -large in it
    }
    var highRes = src.replace(".jpg", "-large.jpg");
  });
```

Comment: Invert your if ... that's terrible code style to have an empty statement block like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function resize(){
  $('.image').each(function() {
    var image = $(this).find('.image img'),
      src = $(this).find('img').attr('src')
      isLarge = /\-large/.test(src);
    if ($(window).width() > 1920 && !isLarge) {
      image.attr("src", src.replace(".jpg", "-large.jpg"));
    }
    else if (isLarge) {
      image.attr("src", src.replace("-large.jpg", ".jpg"));
    }
  });
}
```

We only replace the src if it needs to be changed.